# How can I combine two fields into one in django by using serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is it possible to combine two fields, for example, `age_from` and `age_to` to key named `age` and dictionary value. Like this:

```
age : {
    from: 18,
    to: null
}
```

My models:

```
# models.py

class Banner(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = WEBPField(
        verbose_name='Image',
        upload_to=banner_folder,
    )
    link = models.URLField()
    view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    age_from = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    age_to = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}. {self.text}"

    def count_increase(self):
        self.view_count += 1
        self.save()
```

My serializers:

```
# serializers.py

class BannerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Banner
        fields = ["id", "text", "description", "image", "link"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make a custom field:

```
class AgoField(serializers.Field):
    source_attrs = None

    def run_validation(self, primitive_value):
        return {
            'ago_from': primitive_value['from'],
            'ago_to': primitive_value['to'],
        }

    def get_attribute(self, instance):
        return {'from': instance.ago_from, 'to': instance.ago_to}

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value
```

```
# serializers.py


class BannerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ago = AgoField()
    image = Base64ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Banner
        fields = ['id', 'ago', 'text', 'description', 'image', 'link']
```

the `AgoField` still requires some extra finetuning, like validators, etc. but this is the basic implementation for a "happy path".